# Can I declare a method as friend in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

**CONCLUSION: Yes, but Intellisense won't like it as of VC++ 11.0.60610.01**

I generally don't use friendship, but this time I really need it, and I can't get it to work in Visual Studio 2012. I think it might be an intellisense bug (the code compiles fine) but I just wanted to see if there was something wrong with my code. This reproduces the problem:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    int fun(B b);
};

class B
{
public:
    friend int A::fun(B b);
    B() : member(0) {}
private:
    int member;
};

int A::fun(B b)
{
    return b.member; // Error: B::member is inaccessible.
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    std::cout << a.fun(b);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code [compiles fine on codepad](http://codepad.org/PL5bFFGX) but returns an Intellisense error in VS2012. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually getting that error from the compiler?  Or are you getting it from intellisense? (i.e. when you mouse over the red squiggly lines)

Comment: "Visual Studio 2012" is an IDE, not a language. Please learn the difference. There are several languages that can be used in the VS IDE. Your question is about Microsoft C++ 2012, and has absolutely nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: @KenWhite: Actually, this question has very much to do with the IDE Visual Studio 2012.  It also has to do with the language C++ of course, that's why he tagged it with both.

Comment: @Benjamin: How so? Visual Studio only runs the MS C++ compiler and examines/returns the output. Once again, Visual Studio is not a language, it's an IDE. The problem is with the MSVC++ compiler, if it's a language error. If it's not a language error and is related to Visual Studio, it's an IDE question and not a language question. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @KenWhite: Visual Studio the IDE has a C++ language parser built into it, from the EDG C++ compiler, which is totally different from the C++ parser built into Microsoft Visual C++!  So in this case, there really are two C++ languages operating, and it sounds like the EDG one (which nobody knows is by EDG, so they call it "Visual Studio") is the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite: No, the problem is not with the compiler. The problem is with intellisense, which runs actively as an integral part of the IDE while C++ code is being edited.  Nobody here is confused about the difference between a language and an IDE.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I've updated the OP to clarify the error is reported only in Intellisense. I'm asking the question because I thought Intellisense might be flagging an issue that the compiler isn't reporting or something (I don't know if Intellisense reports warnings for example).

Comment: @KenWhite Intellisense is part of the IDE. If I had mentioned the VC++ compiler I'd have gotten a comment from some other genius claiming I should learn the difference between Intellisense and a compiler. It was an impossible situation, I did my best.

Comment: @ausairman: Thanks for clarifying that the question was about Intellisense. I'll overlook the "some other genius", which is a little impolite. :-) My phrasing with "Please learn the difference" could also be considered a little impolite. My apologies.

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry about that, I was in a fit of fury.

Comment: @ausairman: Yeah, we don't do that here. :-) There are pretty specific (and enforced) guidelines about conduct at SO. As I said though, no worries. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you have no constructors on your classes.  In this case, it seems to be caught up with IntelliSense (which may indeed be a bug, because it doesn't complain if you change the friend clause to `friend class A;`), and that's throwing you off:

> IntelliSense: member "B::member" (declared at line 18) is inaccessible

The real error (compiler is treating warnings as errors by default) is this:

> error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'b' used

Here's how I invoked:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
    std::cout << a.fun(b);
    return 0;
}
```

It will builds (and IntelliSense won't complain) if you specify your own default constructor for `B` such that `member` is initialised:

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : member(0) {}
private:
    int member;
    friend int A::fun(B b);
};
```

Comment: Please see my updated code in the OP; I'm still getting that error. Does the code I have there give an intellisense error for you?

Comment: Yeah it still highlights that line with a red squiggly underline, but I don't get an error in the build output.  Looks like intellisense is not smart enough to deal with member function friendship.

Comment: FYI my VS 2012 is Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

Comment: OK Thanks, I'm using 11.0.6x. I'll have a whinge over at MS forums and see what they say - I was thinking of trying VS2013 anyway. Thanks!